# I can not build iPhone app's project

Tags: iphone, xcode

I downloaded those 2 open source iPhone app from github

https://github.com/indisoluble/Barcode-Reader

https://github.com/forresty/Dictionary

And tried to build them by xcode 4.3.3
but they have same error message.

"The run destination iPhone 5.1 simulator is not valid for running the scheme'BarcodeReaderClientXcode3'"

Why was it happened??
I just want to run it by simulator.

Is there any way to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check "Build Settings" and change "iOS Deployment Target" to iOS 4.3 this may help.